# How to create TextWatcher common class for multiple EditText in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, textwatcher

I am creating a verification screen with 4 `EditText`. And I create one common sub-class of `TextWatcher` in Kotlin: see below code (the code might be right or wrong).

When I use the below code it crashes the application.

> view.etTwo.requestFocus()

**Crash Log**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.EditText.requestFocus()' on a null object reference
        at com.mindfulness.greece.activity.ConfirmationCodeActivity$GenericTextWatcher.afterTextChanged(ConfirmationCodeActivity.kt:123)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:8007)
```

And here are the classes:

```
class GenericTextWatcher(var view: View) : TextWatcher {
    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
        val text: String = s.toString();
        when(view.id) {
            R.id.etOne -> {
                 if(text.length==1){
                      view.etTwo.requestFocus()
                 }
            }
            R.id.etTwo -> {
                 if(text.length==1){
                     view.etThree.requestFocus()
                 }
            }
            R.id.etThree -> {
                if(text.length==1){
                     view.etFour.requestFocus()
                }
            }
             R.id.etFour -> {}

                }
            }

    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you're trying to select `etOne`, `etTwo`, `etThree` & `etFour` from **INSIDE** the view you receive on `TextWatcher`.
The view you access in the function `afterTextChanged(s: Editable?)`
is already the editTexts you're willing to `requestFocus()` on.

The view you're accessing is one of the 4 `TextView`s you have. You need to change the logic here in order to have the access to other `TextView`s

Answer (score 0):

view.etTwo is null as view is the EditText you're currently editing and it doesn't contain all other edittexts.

You could call view.getParent() list all views in parent, find the next one and focus on it. Lots of work!

Or to make it more generic you could extend EditText Like this:

```
fun EditText.onTextChange(onAfterTextChanged: OnAfterTextChangedListener) {
    addTextChangedListener(object :TextWatcher{
        private var text = ""

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) = Unit

        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
            if (s?.length == 1) {
                onAfterTextChanged.complete()
            }
        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) = Unit
    })
}

interface OnAfterTextChangedListener {
    fun complete ()
}
```

Then in you activity where you have the edittexts, call something like this:

```
etOne.onTextChange(object: OnAfterTextChangedListener {
    override fun complete() {
        etTwo.requestFocus()
    }
})

etTwo.onTextChange(object: OnAfterTextChangedListener {
    override fun complete() {
        etThree.requestFocus()
    }
})
```

This creates a new method in EditText called `onTextChange` (could be called whatever). This method calls back to your `OnAfterTextChangedListener` in your Activity where you have access to all your edittexts. And it will be called afterTextChanged if the length of the text equals 1.

Comment: The view **ARE** the `EditText` otherwise the checks on Ids would fail

Answer (score 0):

> TextWatcher common class for multiple EditText

```
class GenericTextWatcher internal constructor(private val view: View) :
    TextWatcher {
    override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        val text = editable.toString()
        when (view.id) {
            R.id.otp1 -> if (text.length == 1) edit1.requestFocus()
            R.id.otp2 -> if (text.length == 1) edit2.requestFocus() else if (text.isEmpty()) edit1.requestFocus()
            R.id.otp3 -> if (text.length == 1) edit3.requestFocus() else if (text.isEmpty()) edit2.requestFocus()
            R.id.otp4 -> if (text.isEmpty()) edit4.requestFocus()
        }
    }

    override fun beforeTextChanged(
        arg0: CharSequence,
        arg1: Int,
        arg2: Int,
        arg3: Int
    ) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    override fun onTextChanged(
        arg0: CharSequence,
        arg1: Int,
        arg2: Int,
        arg3: Int
    ) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

> Use into your class like this

```
edit1.addTextChangedListener(GenericTextWatcher(edit1))
edit2.addTextChangedListener(GenericTextWatcher(edit2))
edit3.addTextChangedListener(GenericTextWatcher(edit3))
edit4.addTextChangedListener(GenericTextWatcher(edit4))
```